# Is there any way to import executable JAR file in Talend?

Tags: jar, talend, talend-mdm

i'm trying to import an Executable jar in talend which i need to process. is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

- Drop a `tSystem` component from the Palette to the design workspace.
- Double-click tSystem to open its Component view.
- Select the `Use Single Command` option to activate its `Command field` and type in the command for running the jar.
- In the Standard Output drop-down list, select to both console and global variable.
- Press F6 to run this Job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tLibraryLoad component and add the custom library.

[image]

You can also use tJava component to call the library